# Date in the format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss without the Z

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime-format

I am trying to find the SQL syntax to get the date into the following format;

`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` without the Z but with the T included.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: [CONVERT (Transact-SQL) - Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles)

Comment: I would also like the milliseconds removed

Comment: So use the appropriate `varchar` length, @Dee . from that documentation I just linked: *"When converting smalldatetime to character data, the styles that include seconds or milliseconds show zeros in these positions. When converting from datetime or smalldatetime values, use an appropriate char or varchar data type length to truncate unwanted date parts."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CONVERT (Transact-SQL) - Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles):

> ## Date and Time styles
>
> For a date or time data type expression, style can have one of the
> values shown in the following table. Other values are processed as 0.
> Beginning with SQL Server 2012 (11.x), the only styles supported, when
> converting from date and time types to datetimeoffset, are 0 or 1. All
> other conversion styles return error 9809.
>
> *Note: SQL Server supports the date format, in Arabic style, with the Kuwaiti
> algorithm.*
>
> ```
> Without century (yy) (1)    |With century (yyyy)     |Standard                |Input/Output (3)
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> -                           |0 or 100 (1,2)          |Default for datetime    |mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM) 
>                             |                        |and smalldatetime       |     
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 1                           |101                     |U.S.                    |1 = mm/dd/yy
>                             |                        |                        |101 = mm/dd/yyyy
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 2                           |102                     |ANSI                    |2 = yy.mm.dd
>                             |                        |                        |102 = yyyy.mm.dd
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 3                           |103                     |British/French          |3 = dd/mm/yy
>                             |                        |                        |103 = dd/mm/yyyy
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 4                           |104                     |German                  |4 = dd.mm.yy
>                             |                        |                        |104 = dd.mm.yyyy
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 5                           |105                     |Italian                 |5 = dd-mm-yy
>                             |                        |                        |105 = dd-mm-yyyy
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 6                           |106 (1)                 | -                      |6 = dd mon yy
>                             |                        |                        |106 = dd mon yyyy
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 7                           |107 (1)                 | -                      |7 = Mon dd, yy
>                             |                        |                        |107 = Mon dd, yyyy
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 8 or 24                     |108                     | -                      |hh:mi:ss
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> -                           |9 or 109 (1,2)          |Default + milliseconds  |mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (or PM)
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 10                          |110                     |USA                     |10 = mm-dd-yy
>                             |                        |                        |110 = mm-dd-yyyy
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 11                          |111                     |JAPAN                   |11 = yy/mm/dd
>                             |                        |                        |111 = yyyy/mm/dd
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 12                          |112                     |ISO                     |12 = yymmdd
>                             |                        |                        |112 = yyyymmdd
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> -                           |13 or 113 (1,2)         |Europe default +        |dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm (24h)
>                             |                        |milliseconds            |
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 14                          |114                     | -                      |hh:mi:ss:mmm (24h)
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> -                           |20 or 120 (2)           |ODBC canonical          |yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss (24h)
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> -                           |21 or 25 or 121 (2)     |ODBC canonical (with    |yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm (24h)
>                             |                        |milliseconds) default   |
>                             |                        |for time, date,         |
>                             |                        |datetime2, and          |
>                             |                        |datetimeoffset          |
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> 22                          | -                      |U.S.                    |mm/dd/yy hh:mi:ss AM (or PM)
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> -                           |23                      |ISO8601                 |yyyy-mm-dd
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> -                           |126 (4)                 |ISO8601                 |yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (no spaces)
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------    
> -                           |127(6, 7)               |ISO8601 with time zone  |yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ (no spaces)
>                             |                        |Z.                      |
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> -                           |130 (1,2)               |Hijri (5)               |dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM
> ----------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------------------------------
> -                           |131 (2)                 |Hijri (5)               |dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM
> ```
>
> When converting smalldatetime to character data, the styles that include seconds or milliseconds show zeros in these positions. When converting from datetime or smalldatetime values, use an appropriate char or varchar data type length to truncate unwanted date parts.

So, you can see that the appropriate style you need is 126 and the length is 19.